# How can I restore the original Sitecore Roles that ship with Sitecore CMS 6.x?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I want to restore the original Sitecore roles such as Sitecore Client Authoring.  I have another "clean" install on 6.3.1 I can copy data from.  Can I copy the rows from that instance's aspnet_Roles table?  What else would be required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't copy the the data over directly as the ID's that ASP.NET membership uses might not match.  You can try serializing the roles from the clean install, then reverting them in the instance where you want to restore.

When you serialize them, they will get written to the 'serialization' folder inside your Data folder.  Copy that to the same directory on the other instance and then use the role manager in the target instance to restore them.

Comment: I've had bad experiences with this tool in the past... Won't a "Revert All" (which would be required) overwrite my existing roles?

Comment: Yep, I just confirmed this.  I suppose I can serialize on site A.  Then on Site B... then copy roles from Site B to Site A and THEN revert.

Comment: Thanks, ddysart.  I got over my fear of serialization and just used that.  Worked fine.  This is just a dangerous tool for the uninitiated!  Luckily I've had some experience with it.

Comment: Yeah, you have to make sure EVERYTHING is in the serialization folder, or it will be gone (learned the hard way)

Comment: Out of interest, why did you not just package up the Roles?  http://snag.gy/oZdBc.jpg